# Will Canvas and / or SVG do transformations (move, scale, rotate)?

Tags: canvas, svg

I was given a task to develop an online flyer where the object must be resizable, movable, draggable and rotatable. Which technology will cover all these capabilities?

I tried to use jcanvas. Whilst it can be draggable, it seems it can't do resizing and rotation.

Comment: Try fabric.js. Check these demos: http://fabricjs.com/demos/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both SVG and Canvas will do transformations: move, scale, rotate.**

Since SVG elements are actually DOM elements, they have the plumbing for transforming built into each element. But you must still manage those SVG transforms (manage == trigger / respond to transformations).

An object drawn onto Canvas becomes like dried paint on an artist's canvas. To do transforms of a particular object on Canvas, you must clear the Canvas and redraw each object in its current position. And like SVG, you must manage those transforms with your own javascript.

There are libraries that automatically do the transformation management for you.

A Lib for SVG: http://snapsvg.io/

Libs for Canvas: http://fabricjs.com/ and http://konvajs.github.io/

I'm not recommending a particular Lib. These are just Libs I've used and know them to work well.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks. One more question, is SVG savable and editable? Meaning it can be saved onto jpg/pdf and reedited later on?

Comment: @user1576748. Currently SVG can't be directly converted to an image (again for security reasons). The workaround is to draw the final SVG onto a Canvas element and use Canvas's `.toDataURL` method to export the SVG-onCanvas to an image. This workaround works in Chrome and Firefox, but fails in Internet Explorer for security reasons.